# thednp/jQueryTween: I would like to know if there is something like onComplete event?

Tags: jquery, plugins

https://github.com/thednp/jQueryTween
I am using this JQuery Plugin which I am now stuck at finding some event like onComplete. Anyone been through that before?

```
$('#object1').jQueryTween({
    from: {
        translate: {
            x: 500 
        }
    }, 
    to: { 
        translate: { 
            y: 0 
        },
        rotate: {
            z: -360
        }
    },
    duration: 3000, 
    easing: TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out
}).onComplete({ console.log("done") }); //I would like to know how to do something like this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://github.com/thednp/jQueryTween#advanced-example) , [jQueryTween](http://thednp.github.io/jQueryTween/)

```
$('#object1').jQueryTween({
    from: {
        translate: {
            x: 500 
        }
    }, 
    to: { 
        translate: { 
            y: 0 
        },
        rotate: {
            z: -360
        }
    },
    duration: 3000, 
    easing: TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out
    },
    // callback when tween is finished
    function() {
      // do some cool stuff when tween finished animating
      console.log("done")
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the jQuery repository from github for KUTE.js.

Check it out https://github.com/thednp/kute.js

Demo, documentation & examples here http://thednp.github.io/kute.js